# OneDrive Excel CodeEditor Type Issue

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, sharepoint, onedrive

Having struggle with the following code (must use SharePoint Excel code editor, I am linking this to Microsoft Power Automate Flows)

What I am trying to do:

- Open my two documents with my data
- Compare the info in both documents
- Check the lines that have same info in column H of both files
- If value of File1 exists in File2, copy and paste it into File3 + add the info of the line (from File1) and add to it the info of the same line in column K from file 2

```
Excel.run(function (context) {
  //open files
  var file1 = context.workbook.application.workbooks.open("pathfile1.xlsx");
  var file2 = context.workbook.application.workbooks.open("pathfile2.xlsx");

  // get worksheet of files
  var sheet1 = file1.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
  var sheet2 = file2.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

  // column range i want to compare between both documents
  var range1 = sheet1.getRange("H:H");
  var range2 = sheet2.getRange("H:H");

  // load data
  range1.load("values");
  range2.load("values");

  return context.sync().then(function () {
    // comparison
    var data1 = range1.values;
    for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
      var value = data1[i][0];

      // check if it exists
      if (value !== "") {
        var existsInFile2 = false;
        var data2 = range2.values;
        for (var j = 0; j < data2.length; j++) {
          if (data2[j][0] === value) {
            existsInFile2 = true;
            break;
          }
        }

        // if exists, copy and paste into do3
        if (existsInFile2) {
          var rowToCopy = sheet1.getRange("A" + (i + 1) + ":Z" + (i + 1));
          var destinationRange = file1.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").getRange("A1");

          // 
          rowToCopy.copyTo(destinationRange);

          // path3
          var file3Path = "pathfile3.xlsx";

          // save file3
          return file1.saveCopyAs(file3Path).then(function (file3) {
            // add infos of additional column
            var sheet3 = file3.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
            var range2B = sheet2.getRange("L:L");
            range2B.load("values");

            return context.sync().then(function () {
             
              var data2B = range2B.values;
              var columnBValues = [];
              for (var k = 0; k < data2B.length; k++) {
                columnBValues.push([data2B[k][0]]);
              }

              // add the new column at the end of the document of file3
              var usedRange3 = sheet3.getUsedRange();
              var lastColumn = usedRange3.getLastColumn();
              var destinationRangeB = usedRange3.getCell(1, lastColumn + 1);
              destinationRangeB.values = columnBValues;

              // save
              return file3.save();
            });
          });
        }
      }
    }

    // Close
    file1.close();
    file2.close();

    return context.sync();
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

I get this set of identical errors, even though I tried replacing the `var`s with specific types.

```
Error: See line 3, column 7: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
See line 4, column 7: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
See line 7, column 7: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
See line 8, column 7: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
See line 11, column 7: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
See line 12, column 7: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
See line 20, column 9: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
See line 22, column 11: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
See line 27, column 13: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
See line 37, column 15: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
See line 38, column 15: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
See line 49, column 17: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
See line 50, column 17: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
See line 55, column 19: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
See line 62, column 19: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
See line 63, column 19: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
See line 64, column 19: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
See line 56, column 19: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
```

Comment: "Please declare a type for the variable" <- do that?

Comment: I have been trying to declare a type for 25 times or more and I always had the issue, same error in every case/try

Comment: I'd suggest you give a [mre] of that, then.